# How can I simulate the multiple judges judging the same case in R?

Tags: r, simulation, modeling, noise

I need to simulate multiple judges (5) giving grades from 1-10 to the same 10 cases and then add different types of noise to it.

This is the code I have so far (adapted from the code my professor gave us). The problem is that it assigns only 2 cases per judge, instead of all 10.

```r
Ncases = 10

Njudges = 5

NCategories = 10 ## Number of categories
meanLik = 7.5 ## must be smaller than the number of categories
sdLik = 1.5

M = meanLik/NCategories ## mean of beta distribution
VAR = (sdLik/NCategories)^2 ## variance of beta distribution
tau = (M * (1-M))/VAR - 1 ## parameter for solving a couple of equations

## The shape parameters also called alpha and beta determine the Shape of the distribution
shape1 = M*tau 
shape2 = (1-M)*tau

truevalues = rbeta(Ncases, shape1, shape2)*NCategories

trueChoices = ceiling(truevalues)

data = as.data.frame(cbind("truevalues" = truevalues, 
                           "trueChoices" = trueChoices))

data = as.data.frame(cbind("truevalues" = truevalues, 
                           "trueChoices" = trueChoices, 
                            "judge" = rep(seq(1,Njudges/Ncases), Ncases)))

Levels = c(1,0,-2,-1,-1)

data$gradevalues = data$truevalues 

for (i in (1: Njudges)){
  
  data$gradevalues[data$judge == i] = data$truevalues[data$judge == i] + 
             Levels[i]
}

data$gradevalues[which(data$gradevalues > 10)] = 10
data$gradevalues[data$gradevalues < 0] = 0

data$gradeChoices = ceiling(data$gradevalues)

ggplot(data, aes(x =gradeChoices))+ 
  facet_wrap(.~ judge,nrow = 4 )+
    geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(prop)), stat="count")+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,.5), xlim = c(1,NCategories))

# average grades per judge
tapply(data$gradeChoices, data$judge, mean)

# standard deviation across judges == level noise
sd(tapply(data$gradeChoices, data$judge, mean))
```

I tried adapting this line of code:

```r
data = as.data.frame(cbind("truevalues" = truevalues, 
                           "trueChoices" = trueChoices, 
                            "judge" = rep(seq(1,Njudges/Ncases), Ncases)))
```

I adapted it to:

```r
data = as.data.frame(cbind("truevalues" = truevalues, 
                           "trueChoices" = trueChoices, 
                            "judge" = rep(seq(1,Njudges), Ncases)))
```

When I then look at the data set it looks good, but it's still not correct in the `ggplot`